# Application of Tonellis Theorem for expected values

Tags: lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I tried to understand the following equation.
[image]

According to the solution, the second "=" is justified by Tonellis Theorem. However, I struggled showing that the assumptions of Tonellis Theorem hold in our case. If one uses the definition of the expected value, I see that $y\mathbb{1}_{L-a>x}$ is measurable, however I do not see why this is $L^1$-integrable. Can someone help me understanding why this function is $L^1$-integrable?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, Tonelli's theorem doesn't require the function to be integrable.

Comment: This is correct. You just need non-negativity. See the “Tonelli’s Theorem for Non-Negative Measurable Functions” section on this page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem_for_non-negative_measurable_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone already pointed out in the comments, Tonelli's theorem applies to nonnegative functions, regardless of integrability. The first equality expresses $(L-a)^+ = \int_{[0,(L-a)^+)}1\,dx = \int_{[0,\infty)}1_{[0,(L-a)^+)}(x)\,dx$. Sometimes $1_{[0,(L-a)^+)}(x)$ is also written as $1_{\{0\le x < (L-a)^+\}}$. In either case, the integrand is an indicator function, which takes only the values $0$ or $1$. Therefore the second equality is just an invocation of Tonelli's theorem applied to the $\{0,1\}$-valued function $1_{\{0\le x<(L-a)^+\}}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you. I forgot that property

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Can you quickly repeat why $y\mathbb{1}_{L-a>x}$ is non-negative?

Comment: @Anton2107: I am not sure what the $y$ is in your comment, but I updated my answer with some more details I hope are helpful.

Comment: Yes, very helpful. My mistake was to do the calculations for a random variable with density and I did not use the definition of expected value for an arbitrary real-valued variable. Thanks!!!!